# How to make Quarkus to listen on all network interfaces instead of localhost?

Tags: quarkus

When I run my Quarkus application it listens/binds to localhost only by default.

How can I alter this behavior?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With the inclusion of [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1307) PR in Quarkus, starting with version `0.12.0` the configuration explained in the following section will no longer be needed since Quarkus will use `0.0.0.0` as the default host.

---

By default Quarkus only listens on localhost (127.0.0.1). To make Quarkus listen on all network interfaces (something that is very handy for example when running inside a Docker container or Kubernetes Pod), the `quarkus.http.host` property needs to be set.

If you always want your Quarkus application to listen on all interfaces you can set
`quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` in your `application.properties` (under `src/main/resources`).

If you would rather keep the default setting and only override at runtime, you can do that as follows:

When running a Quarkus application in JVM mode you can set the port using the quarkus.http.host System property to 0.0.0.0. 
For example:

```
java -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -jar example-runner.java
```

The same property applies to GraalVM Native Mode images. 
For example:

```
./example-runner -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I see in quarkus.io/guides/all-config, that on dev mode it defaults to localhost.This looks to have been changed in Quarkus 1.9

Comment: Will this make ipv6 work by default? It doesn't seems to be working on localhost